# Joomla Mod_Menu and Custom Bootstrap nav

Tags: php, html, joomla, bootstrap-4

I have created a new template with bootstrap studio (Full template).
I joined it with Joomla, everything is working fine except the menu..

Here is my "Nav" element - Standard bootstrap with some custom JS to slide menu out from right side, not from top :

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-dark" style="width:100%;padding-left:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;">
            <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>" style="font-weight:bold;font-family:'Titillium Web', sans-serif;"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/assets/img/Logo.png" style="height:30px;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:5px;">Romuring.ee</a>
                <button
                    class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" style="font-family:'Titillium Web', sans-serif;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);background-repeat:repeat-y;background-size:cover;"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1" style="font-family:'Titillium Web', sans-serif;font-weight:bold;">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto" style="background-position:center;background-size:cover;background-repeat:repeat-y;">            
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu-1"  />
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

and now I know that I need to make an "override" to the mod_menu to get my "css" to work with menu.

At the moment it has "standard" blue links and is not affected with my style.

PS! I have no clue how to make it work..

I made override files, I assume that I should edit the default_url.php file?

This is how my menu is:

[image: Thats how my menu is :]

and this is how it should be:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla needs a module for menu. thats where you can style it.

my way was menu module overwrite, followed thisone :

https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=651988

Comment: Please add a bit more explanation about your solution so that your post is more educational/helpful to future researchers experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Updated with link.